# How to implement countdown function like Yahoo's APP News Digest

Tags: ios

[image: countdonw gif]
[image: countdownView]

I can use `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath` to draw the circle, I can also use this property `CAShapeLayer.strokeEnd` to control the progress. But the fast scrolling of path and time , I do not know how to implement.

Now I think the approach is to calculate the time difference between the two , and then use the time difference to circulation .

For example, The time difference between the two is 1000 seconds , should I have to set strokeEnd  and the middle of the Label 1000 cycles ？ Or that implement good results it ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note : **StrokeEnd accepts value between `0 - 1`**

Lets Say,
See in your case circle represents the remaining time it will take to appear new feed. lets say **3PM.**

so **3 PM** will be your `nextFeedTime = 3PM` and,
you got this feed at **12PM** so `feedTime = 12PM`.

So now you will have start and end value of `feedTime=12PM - nextFeedTime=3PM`

So `feedTime` is `0` for `strokeEnd` and `nextFeedTime` is `1` for StrokeEnd.

When you open app you will got `currentTime` which is initially initialised with `feedTime` and later it will be replaced all the time with current time stamp.

Lets assume `currentTime` is `1 PM`.

Now we can calculate ratio to animate `strockEnd` property

`strokeEnd = currentTime / nextFeedTime`

and animate strokeEnd accordingly. hope this will helps you!

Comment: Thank you, I use CABasicAnimation to implement this effect , but the effect numbers scrolling fast in gif how to implement?

Comment: For that you can set text on  Progress of animations